# Passportjs authentication for multiple angular apps

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to do something but I dont have experience with SSO/OAUTH/SAML/JWT authentications for multiple apps.

In near future my company will have for example 3 angular apps.

So, what I need? Below, the steps:

1. User will enter on "firstapp.com", angular will handle the tokens and check if user has session, if not, user will redirected to loginapp.com
2. The user is request to enter credentials
3. After logged in, user will be redirected to "firstapp.com/?jwt=4mkms9394i2fm29" (for example).

Now, imagine if user enter on secondapp.com, user is already authenticated yeah? So, user dont need to be redirected to loginapp.com and enter his credentials.

I really need a solution like google.

Can someone give me more information about how can I do this?

Comment: Other thing, probably, each app can have different rest api entrypoints, for example:

api.firstapp.com
api.secondapp.com

Comment: After successful login create a jwt token and add it to response headers and save token key to db then when a request comes to your server check headers for jwt token and compare the key. Done.

Comment: How can I check it in api.firstapp.com, api.secondapp.com?

Comment: After login you redirect user to e.g. firstapp.com/login/<token that you saved in db> firstapp will check the token and generate jwt and redirect to firstapp.com/ (user will not see the login redirect) now you have jwt and you can use it to call apis. Each API needs to check jwt against db